# Select from table where ids are not in list of ids

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to select from a table where the `primary_no` (`VARCHAR(20)`) does not include any of the strings in the @IDS variable, but it's not working and I have tried using a CTE, not exists and not in. Neither of them work. The query still selects all of the data even those with the primary_no that are in the @IDS variable.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LinkProc]
    @IDS VARCHAR(MAX)
/*
DECLARE @IDS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @IDS = '
''00000447'',
''0000300'',
''2900071'',
''2900192''
'
EXEC LinkProc @IDS = @IDS    
*/
AS
    WITH cte (id) AS
    (
        SELECT *  
        FROM dbo.splitstring(@IDS)
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM link_tb 
    WHERE grp_id = 4
      AND status_cd = 'A' 
      AND primary_no NOT IN (SELECT id FROM cte)
```

I have also tried this with no luck:

```
SELECT * 
FROM link_tb lt 
WHERE grp_id = 4 
  AND status_cd = 'A' 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM cte c WHERE lt.primary_no = c.id)
```

The result set from calling (`SELECT id FROM cte`):

```
'00000447'
'0000300'
'2900071'
'2900192'
```

I found a solution to this problem, I answered below.

Comment: We have created this splitstring function manually. So when I call this (SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring(@IDS) it does give me a list of the split strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution to my problem. The IDS were parsed into a table and I selected from there. My main issue was I had set the @IDS with incorrect formatting, there were line breaks in the string. Upon putting them together with no spaces it worked.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LinkProc]

    @IDS VARCHAR(MAX)

/*

DECLARE @IDS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @IDS = '00000447,0000300,2900071,2900192'

EXEC LinkProc @IDS = @IDS

*/

AS

SELECT * 
FROM link_tb 
WHERE grp_id = 4 
    AND status_cd = 'A' 
    AND primary_no NOT IN (SELECT param_value FROM dbo.PARSE_PARAM_LIST(@IDS, ','))
```

Answer (score 2):

---

**Disclaimer**: Turns out, from the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200857/discussion-between-hypnagogia-and-larnu), that the OP is not using 2014, but 2005 (which is completely unsupported and has been for years). As a result the answer using a table type parameter will not work because the functionality does not exist.

I have left the answer there, however, for future users who have a similar question.

---

Instead of using a delimited list, use a table-type parameter

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.PrimaryList AS TABLE (primary_no varchar(20) NOT NULL);
GO

ALTER PROC dbo.LinkProc @IDs dbo.PrimaryList READONLY AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.link_tb l
         LEFT JOIN @IDs I ON l.primary_no = I.primary_no
    WHERE grp_id = 4
      AND status_cd = 'A' 
      AND I.primary_no IS NULL;

END;
GO
```

You can then call the SP as so:

```
DECLARE @IDs dbo.PrimaryList;
INSERT INTO @IDs
VALUES('00000447'),
      ('0000300'),
      ('2900071'),
      ('2900192');

EXEC dbo.LinkProc @IDs;
```

---

**Edit:**
As for why what you have isn't working, it's because you're quote wrapping your values. What you're doing is the equivlent of:

```
EXEC dbo.LinkProc @IDs = '''00000447''';
```

The value of `primary_no` isn't going to be `'00000447'` it's just going to be `00000447`. If you *have* to pass a delimited list (which I suggest against, and I wouldn't be surprised if your function using a `WHILE`, and if it does you **need** to remove that), then don't quote the values:

```
EXEC dbo.LinkProc @IDs = '00000447,0000300,2900071,2900192';
```

Comment: The @IDS I'm passing in are coming from another table and the list of the IDS can be very long. Is there a way to do this without hard-coding the values?

Comment: Yes, use an `INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM` statement @hypnagogia , instead of an `INSERT INTO...VALUES...` statement

Comment: If you can have a very long list, then using an table-value parameter is an even better idea, @hypnagogia . The performance of a statement using `IN` can degrade with a (very) long list.

Comment: I'm getting errors trying to implement your solution. I may be writing it incorrectly. But for the INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM you mentioned, I won't be selecting from a table within the query, I will be sending in the list of @IDS as a parameter.

Comment: That's what i'm doing above, @hypnagogia : `EXEC dbo.LinkProc @IDs;`

Comment: YOU say you're getting an "error", but you didn't say what error. What are you doing for the `INSERT INTO... SELECT...FROM` statement?

Comment: I'm doing this, where @IDLIST is the list of ids I'm sending in: INSERT INTO dbo.PrimaryList(primary_loan_no)
VALUES(@IDLIST)

Comment: I also don't think I have permissions to create a table type. I'm getting error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: @hypnagogia No, you `INSERT` into the table type parameter... Look at my `INSERT` statement, I insert the values into `@IDs`. Are you not familiar with inserting data into one table from another? It's a very common SQL operation.

Comment: *"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."* is not a permission error, you've done something else wrong. That statement does not generate that error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200857/discussion-between-hypnagogia-and-larnu).

Comment: A basic `INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM` looks like this @hypnagogia `INSERT INTO MyTable(Col1, Col2) SELECT OT.Col1, OT.Col2 FROM OtherTable OT;`